# Use deeplink with more than two waypoints in HERE WeGo application

Tags: android, here-api

Is it possible use deeplink with more than two waypoints in HERE WeGo application?
I tried to use, see below, but application ignore waypoints. I tried put URL to webbrowser everything works.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://share.here.com/r/49.770186522681,18.36631150207348/49.77332538162088,18.36242766341992/49.777010917825464,18.399462224441113/49.677753757381055,18.33102549900111"));
intent.setPackage("com.here.app.maps");
startActivity(intent);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this is possible, if you check our documentation about the URL Format, you will see the parameters depend on the shared object. For places, this is a Share ID. **For routes**, it is a set of waypoints separated by slashes. For the location, it is a pair of coordinates.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/deeplink-web/dev_guide/topics/request-format.html

Comment: I read this article and my example is just by this format and not working.